# How can I pass variable numbers into PayPal REST API and give customers a receipt?

Tags: javascript, java, html, paypal

I am building a lottery web application where customers can select their own numbers or get 4 random numbers. How can I carry these numbers that the customer inputs/randomly generates into my shopping cart / paypal button? Thanks for any help. This is my code so far for the generation of random lottery numbers on JSP page.

```
<div id="num1" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="one"></span></div>
<div id="num2" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="two"></span></div>
<div id="num3" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="three"></span></div>
<div id="num4" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="four"></span></div>
                               
                           
 <%-- onclick to execute JavaScript function--%>      
 <button onclick="random()">QuickPick!</button>
</div>
```

This is the JS file to execute the random numbers to be generated.

```
function random(){
 //selects the 4 circles on the page
var one= document.getElementById('one');
var two= document.getElementById('two');
var three= document.getElementById('three');
var four= document.getElementById('four');


//create random number for each of the circles between 1-30
var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var d = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);


//put the random number into each of the 4 circles
one.textContent = a;
two.textContent = b;
three.textContent = c;
four.textContent = d;

}
```

I have set up a PayPal REST API integration by following instructions on the website, I also can use a buy now smart button from PayPal. My question is, how can I issue the customers a receipt of the numbers they have selected up successful purchase of the ticket? Is there a way to pass the values of the JS code into the PayPal checkout page, any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot find a way to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addandmodifythecode) guide, see the bullet #6 which has this example of transferring item information to PayPal:

```js
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
         "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100",
              "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100"
                }
              }
            },
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "First Product Name", /* Shows within upper-right dropdown during payment approval */
                "description": "Optional descriptive text..", /* Item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view */
                "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "50"
                },
                "quantity": "2"
              },
            ]
          }]
      });
    },
```

You can pass the same type of line item information whether using `actions.order.create` to create the order in the client side JS, or the REST API to create the order on the server. It is the same Orders v2 JSON format either way.

(A server-side REST API integration to create and capture the order is the most robust way; you can pair this with a JS SDK button for approval per the guide in bullet #5 of the above link.)

Comment: But if every customer has different numbers the "purchase_units" will always be different instead of say a fixed item and its price, what can I insert into purchase_units to pass these numbers into PayPal, I have little experience with this so I am still confused sorry

Comment: When using the JS SDK buttons, createOrder is called when a button is clicked. At that point do what you need to do to create your purchase_units object with the right information, and create the order with it.

Comment: does the Js SDK button replcae the REST API or where does it go? Thanks for your help

Comment: It goes in the HTML served by our page, and is used for the "Approval" step instead of redirecting, giving a much better experience than redirecting away (your site always stays loaded). It can replace calling the REST API from your server if you use actions.order.create and .capture , but it is most robust to use `fetch` from the button to call 2 endpoints on your server, and have your server call the REST API to create/capture in each case.